# Interface Builder design adaptive to different screen sizes

Tags: ios, interface-builder

How can I adapt my viewers to different iPhone screen sizes? Any link helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked a very strange question. The [iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH1-SW1) allows you to test builds of your app during the development process for various iOS devices -

[image]

Furthermore, since you mentioned Interface Builder - you can use the form-factor button to switch between Apple Retina 3.5-inch form factor and Apple Retina 4-inch form factor while working on Storyboard -

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is a good [blog post](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/2/25/xcode-fix-show-the-iphone-simulator-skin-on-a-retina-display), which can answer your question about iPhone Simulator skins on Retina Display. Also, if you want to stick with non-retina simulator you can use -
`iPhone Simulator >> Window >> Scale >> 75% or 50%`

You need to learn about **Auto Layout** and more specifically how to set constraints.

There is Ray's [Video Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout) on Auto Layout and the [Beginning Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) blog post for iOS 7. Maybe you give the rich Apple documentation a chance: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1)

Comment: I know that, but how can I adjust positions and sizes according to the target device? + I have two laptops, one retina and one regular and I interchange both. The simulators look different on either machine and that makes it bit confusing.

Comment: @ElDude Added an update. Hope, it gives you an idea how you can adjust your iPhone Simulator. You have to be very very specific when asking questions.